# Best way to add support for promises

Tags: javascript

I want to convert an existing package that does not use standard node.js callback styles to support the existing callback style or promises. Consider something like:

```
api.getSomething({prop: ...}, callback)
```

It currently uses the `request` library and `api.getSomething` does something like this:

```
return request({
  url: ...,
  data: ...,
}, callback)
```

The sort of high-level solution seems to me basically to check if `callback` is undefined and if so, return a promise. However, the use of the `request` library seems to complicate this, as I want a `request` library that returns a promise when callback isn't defined, and the request otherwise.

Would it make sense to use the `request-promise` library and if the callback is supplied, call the callback in a `then`, and otherwise just return the data in the `then`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. Make sure to simply always return a promise, and if a callback is supplied call that as well.

```
const promise = request({
  url: …,
  data: …,
});
if (typeof callback == "function") {
    promise.then(result => { callback(null, result); }, error => { callback(error); });
}
return promise;
```

If you're doing this more than once, I'd recommend using a helper function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, both ways work:

1) Callback to Promise:

```
  getSomething(prop, callback) {
    if(!callback) return new Promise((res, rej) => this.getSomething(prop, (err, result) => err ? rej(err) : res(result)));
    //...
    callback(null, "result");
  }
```

2) Promise to callback:

```
  getSomething(prop, callback) {
     const promise = Promise.resolve(/*...*/);
     if(callback) {
      promise.then(res => callback(null, res), callback);
     } else {
      return promise;
     }
  }
```

Which one you use is really up to you. You should consider however that updating a dependency can cause more trouble than you expect (but `request-promise` should be well-maintained though).